# Using the same <List> in multiple Views

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I'm writing a Spring MVC application and am quite new to the concept.

Say I have a Request Mapping to a view that shows a  `<List>` of names.

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/names", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String readCNFG(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("names", names);

    return "viewNames"
}
```

But then within that view there is an 'edit names' option, which should include the same list but within text boxes (in another view, with a separate controller).

Would I have to add same line of `model.addAttribute("names", names);` to each controller that wants to use that `<List>`? This seems repetitive...

Comment: Add a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method, which returns the list. See the spring [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) for additional information .

Comment: @M.Deinum would this be accessible from a separate class (separate controller)?

Comment: No. Only a single controller. If you need it in all controllers you can add it to a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` or use an `interceptor`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that as well. My application is based mainly around a few views, one for viewing a list of people, another for editing/adding to that list. So I wanted a way to break it into separate controllers, one for each main function.

Comment: You generally want to create controllers per domain type so one for handling the people stuff etc. not a controller for each possible request as that makes it hard to have shared functionality/